# Dependent dropdowns in simple_form_for

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a form with 2 dropdowns: collections and books. First dropdown shows all the collections. Unless some collection is chosen, a second dropdown has to be empty. And only when a user choses a collection, the second dropdown has to become filled with books from that collection.

My haml file:

```
= simple_form_for 'reader', url: generate_reader_path do |f|
      = f.input :collection, :collection => @collections.map{|c| [c[:name], c[:id]]}, input_html: { url: get_books_collections_path}
      %br
      = f.input :book, :collection => @books.map{|b| [b[:name], b[:id]]}

:javascript

  // generate books based on chosen collection

  $(function() {
    $('select#reader_collection').change(function() {
      var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
      var params = 'some_id=' + id;
    });
  });
```

When a user chooses a collection he should get into a get_books method in collections_controller:

```
  def get_books
    collection_id = params[:some_id]
    @books = Book.where(collection_id: collection_id)
  end
```

Please help me to move on

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained .

If you want to do it yourself:

Your get books needs to output json:

```
def get_books
  collection_id = params[:some_id]
  @books = Book.where(collection_id: collection_id)

  render json: @books
end
```

The javascript:

```
:javascript

  // generate books based on chosen collection

  $(function() {
    $('select#reader_collection').change(function() {
      var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
      var params = 'some_id=' + id;


        $.ajax({
          #You could use the url set on the first select, set it to an data attribute and retrieve it here with $(select).data 'url'
          url: "/controller/action?id=" + id, 
          type: 'get',
          data: $(this).serialize()
        }).success(function (data) {
          update_select(data);
        });
    });
  });


function update_select(data) {
    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    var options = [];
    json.each(function (key, index) {
        options.push({text: index, value: key});
    });
    $("#select_box").replaceOptions(options);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get Json data from server of selected Collection and then populate the Book Dropdown. So here is a code snippet to do that

**Server Side**

```
def get_books
    collection_id = params[:some_id]
    @books = Book.where(collection_id: collection_id)
    render :json=> @books.map {|book| {:id=>book.id,:title=>book.name}}
end
```

**:javascript**

```
  // generate books based on chosen collection

  $(function() {
    $('select#reader_collection').change(function() {
      var id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
      $.get(("/get_books/?some_id="+id),function(data){
     $.each(data, function( index, book ) {
     $(YOUR_BOOK_DROPDOWN_SELECTOR).append($('<option>').text(book.title).attr('value', book.id))
});
});
        });
      });
```

Replace **YOUR_BOOK_DROPDOWN_SELECTOR** with your actual Dropdown ID/Selector for Book.

P.S Didn't test myself. There might be some glitches

Comment: Nothing happens :( I added a class for books dropdown and replaced YOUR_BOOK_DROPDOWN_SELECTOR with it

Comment: Can you tell me is there any error in Browser Console ? 
Secondly Check the Rails Log that request is receiving at server end with valid collection id or not ?